# Wireless mouse security

Tags: wireless

How secure are wireless mice?

Is it possible to control a wireless mouse from a different computer?

Is it possible to know the mouse movements from a different computer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From testing, I have demonstrated to clients that yes, both of these are possible. The machines are supposed to have a 1 to 1 relationship with the mouse, but for some types of mouse there aren't a lot of ID codes, so you can get overlap.

The same is true for some wireless keyboards.

Simplest solution: if you are worried at all, use wired devices

Comment: Is this a relatively easy thing to do, something where it is possible in all cases, does not take much time etc? or is this more of a "well its possible in some cases with lots of time" type of thing?

Comment: It was quite dependent on the types of devices we tested, some had an immediate problem because they used the same ID, others had no problem during testing, but we reckoned given enough time we could break them. The problem is that the link is unencrypted in most (possibly all) cases.

Comment: But it is not like there are tools that are relatively easy to access that will be able to do this?

Comment: no - I don't think so. It is quite a manual task.

Comment: And even then, mostly mice report back _relative_ movements (dx/dy), so if you're worried, just pick it up between movements, or run the cursor 'past' the edge (most OSes don't seem to let the cursor 'escape').  That'd _probably_ limit them to detecting you clicking in the corners.  Combine this with doing things like just clicking to focus the window, and keyboard shortcuts (from a wired keyboard), and you're good.

Comment: There are some wireless keyboards (and I assume mice) that do support encryption of traffic. Here's a Whitepaper on Logitech's encryption http://www.logitech.com/images/pdf/roem/Logitech_Adv_24_Ghz_Whitepaper_BPG2009.pdf